# React Redux update item quantity (more than just one increment)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have a site where the user can increase the quantity on the product before adding it to cart. Now if the user decided to go back to the product and add 3 more by increasing the quantity on the product, then adding to cart - how do I update the quantity of the existing product in basket?

At the moment I get duplicates of the product with different quantities depending on what is selected.

Here is the code I have for my reducer:

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  items: [],
};

const basket = createSlice({
  name: "basket",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addToBasket: (state, { payload }) => {
        // No idea what to do with this..
      state.items.filter((pizza) => pizza.name === payload.name);

      // This pushes the item fine, but I get multiple of the same item in the cart instead of just updating its quantity
      state.items.push(payload);



      //   state.items.map((pizza) =>
      //     pizza.name === payload.name
      //       ? {
      //           ...pizza,
      //           quantity: pizza.quantity + payload.quantity,
      //         }
      //       : pizza
      //   );


    },
  },
});

export const { addToBasket } = basket.actions;
export const basketItems = (state) => state.basket.items;

export default basket.reducer;
```

The payload is the specific product, it will be an object:

```
{
 name: "product name",
 image: "url.jpeg",
 price: "14.99"
}
```

I can not for the life of me figure out what to do here in order not to mutate the state. Nothing works, I feel like I have tried every possible way but clearly I am missing something.

Any help much appreciated!!!

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually have all the code you need, just need it applied correctly. First check that the item is already in the `items` array or not. If it is already there then copy the existing state and update the matching element. If it is *not* included then append the new item to the end of the array.

```
const basket = createSlice({
  name: "basket",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addToBasket: (state, { payload }) => {
      const item = state.items.find((pizza) => pizza.name === payload.name);

      if (item) {
        state = state.items.map((pizza) =>
          pizza.name === payload.name
            ? {
                ...pizza,
                quantity: pizza.quantity + payload.quantity
              }
            : pizza
        );
      } else {
        state.items.push(payload);
      }
    },
  },
});
```

With Redux-Toolkit you can mutate the state objects so you can likely simplify this a bit. Instead of mapping a new array and setting it back to state, jut mutate the found object.

```
const basket = createSlice({
  name: "basket",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addToBasket: (state, { payload }) => {
      const item = state.items.find((pizza) => pizza.name === payload.name);

      if (item) {
        item.quantity += payload.quantity;
      } else {
        state.items.push(payload);
      }
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: Holy sh... you're a god damn hero, thanks! I wrote this previously too, checking if it exists with find etc, only thing I wasn't doing is setting the items in the state = the map returns!! God damn, there goes 8 hours I'm never going to get back, so relieved, thank you!!

Comment: @Joe Yeah, I'm still getting used to how redux-toolkit allows you to write reducer functions that mutate state. Typically you'd return a ***new*** state object, but with RTK you can just mutate the state. Alternatively I think you could find the index and just mutate the element by index directly. Cheers and good luck.

Comment: this mutating directly with `createSlice` it's something strange for me too. given that, couldn't we mutate item directly once we find a match like `item.quantity =  item.quantity + payload.quantity`, instead mapping items?

Comment: @buzatto Great point. Upon further consideration I think I totally agree with you. I updated my answer with a revised/simplified version. Thanks.

Comment: Ah yes, they use immer behind it. Not entirely sure how that works though haven't looked into it, it does seem bizarre to me, too. I did also try mutating directly , that was my first implementation however that wasn't working for me, more state mutation errors.

Comment: @Joe When I was researching React-Toolkit early on I dug into the source and IIRC a sort of [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) is used to abstract over the state. Though, I admittedly don't recall if this happened in RTK or if that is how immer functions.

Comment: Second one worked for me. Could not get the first one to update state, still showing same quantity. Thank you so much